# Pygame, restarting game results in program closing

Tags: python, pygame

I know this question has been asked before but I'v tried different approaches and I can't seem to be able to fix it.

I know I have to reset my important global variables in order to correctly restart the game.
The reset of those variables is done when lives == 0 -> I reset the global variables, main menu becomes True and Game False which should put me back in the main menu.

However when I run my game, as soon as the lives reach 0 the code finishes and exits -> Process finished with exit code 0.

The issue must be in my while game loop but I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong.
I'v also tried wrapping my game logic in a function, this seems to mess with my game since I only get the frozen state screen, no enemy spawning and not able to move.

Any ideas what might cause this issue?

Full code:

```
import pygame
import pygame_gui
import random

# Initialize game window here
pygame.init()

# Variables for the game window
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
manager = pygame_gui.UIManager((800, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption('Sea Invaders')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # Adds the clock for spawn timers
score_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 36)
multiplier_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 18)

# Sprites, background, UI and music
background = pygame.image.load('Background.jpg')
whale_sprite = pygame.image.load('Whale.png')
speedboat_sprite = pygame.image.load('Speedboat.png')
beam_sprite = pygame.image.load('Beam.png')
life_sprite = pygame.image.load('Life.png')
pirate_boss_sprite_right = pygame.image.load('Pirateboss_right.png')
game_title = pygame_gui.elements.UILabel(relative_rect=pygame.Rect((200, 100), (400, 100)), text='SEA INVADERS',
                                         manager=manager)
description_box = pygame_gui.elements.UILabel(relative_rect=pygame.Rect((150, 250), (500, 100)),
                                              text='Protect the ocean as long as possible by destroying ships',
                                              manager=manager)
start_button = pygame_gui.elements.UIButton(relative_rect=pygame.Rect((350, 400), (100, 50)), text='Start',
                                            manager=manager)
quit_button = pygame_gui.elements.UIButton(relative_rect=pygame.Rect((350, 450), (100, 50)), text='Quit',
                                           manager=manager)


# Classes
class Player():

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        # Variables for the Whale go here
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.mov_speed = 5
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

    def draw(self, window):
        # This function draws the whale using the sprite and the defined location in the class parameters
        window.blit(whale_sprite, (self.x, self.y))
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        # Whale hitbox check
        # pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), self.hitbox, 2)


class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, width, height, mov_speed):
        # Variables for the various enemies
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.mov_speed = mov_speed
        self.image = speedboat_sprite
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randint(64, 734)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-150, -100)
        self.hitbox = (self.rect.x + 22, self.rect.y + 15, 19, 45)
        self.alive = True

    def update(self):
        # This function lets the enemy go forward until the end of the screen
        max_distance = 800 - self.height
        if self.rect.y < max_distance:
            self.rect.y += self.mov_speed

    def hit(self):
        # This function deletes the sprite from the sprite group when hit by an attack from a player
        self.kill()
        self.alive = False


class Boss():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, mov_speed, hitpoints):
        # Variables for the boss objects
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.mov_speed = mov_speed
        self.hitpoints = hitpoints
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 30, self.y + 50, 225, 160)  # Dimensions of the hitbox to make it close to the model
        self.alive = False
        self.killed = False
        self.end_reached = False

    def draw(self, window):
        if self.alive and not self.killed:
            window.blit(pirate_boss_sprite_right, (self.x, self.y))
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 30, self.y + 50, 225, 160)
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0),
                             (self.x + ((self.width / 2) - (self.hitpoints / 2)), self.y + 220, 50, 10))
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 255, 0),
                             (self.x + ((self.width / 2) - (self.hitpoints / 2)), self.y + 220, self.hitpoints, 10))

            # Pirate Boss hitbox check
            # pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), self.hitbox, 2)

    def move(self):
        # This function moves the boss forward. As soon as the boss reaches the end it spawns lower on the screen.
        # If the end is reached the model is deleted and the end_reached parameter is set tot True.
        max_distance = 800 - self.height
        if self.x < (800 + self.width):
            self.x += self.mov_speed

        else:
            self.y += 100
            self.x = -51

        if self.y >= max_distance:
            self.alive = False
            self.end_reached = True

    def hit(self):
        # As soon as the Whale hitpoints reaches 0, the model is overwritten on screen.
        if self.hitpoints <= 0:
            self.killed = True
            return True


class Projectile():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, speed, damage, image):
        # Variables for the player attacks (ranged)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.speed = speed
        self.damage = damage
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

    def checkCollision(self, enemy):
        # This function checks collision with enemies that belong to a Sprite Group.
        self.rect.x = int(self.x)
        self.rect.y = int(self.y)

        # noinspection PyTypeChecker
        return any(pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, enemy, True))


class Hud():
    # class to place the HUDS on the screen (lives, score)
    def __init__(self, x, y, sprite):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.sprite = sprite

    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.sprite, (self.x, self.y))


# Methods
def redrawUI():
    window.blit(background, (0, 0))  # Loads in the background
    whale.draw(window)  # Draws the Whale in the game
    window.blit(speedboat_sprite, (100, 100))
    window.blit(speedboat_sprite, (620, 100))
    manager.draw_ui(window)
    if lives == 0:
        text = f'Game over! Your score: {score}.'
        game_over = score_font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0))
        window.blit(game_over, (200, 200))
    pygame.display.update()


def redrawGameWindow():
    window.blit(background, (0, 0))  # Loads in the background
    whale.draw(window)  # Draws the Whale in the game
    scoreboard = score_font.render(str(score), True, (255, 255, 255))
    multiplier_message = multiplier_font.render(f'multiplier: {multiplier}', True, (255, 255, 255))
    window.blit(scoreboard, (700, 760))
    window.blit(multiplier_message, (85, 766))

    x_life = 0
    # This for loop places the lives next to eachother on the HUD
    for life in range(lives):
        life = Hud(x_life, 760, life_sprite)
        x_life += 25
        life.draw(window)

    for b in bosses:
        b.alive = True
        b.draw(window)
        b.move()

    speedboats.draw(window)
    speedboats.update()

    for fired_beam in beams:
        fired_beam.draw(window)

    pygame.display.update()  # This updates the above changes to the game window

# Game logic here
main_menu = True
game = False
FPS = 100
whale = Player(334, 650, 128, 128)  # Spawns the Player at the start of the game in the middle of the screen
speedboat_locations = (125, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800)
speedboats = pygame.sprite.Group()
bosses = []
beams = []
cooldown = 0
lives = 3
score = 0
speedboat_hits = 0
multiplier = 1
start = pygame.time.get_ticks()


while main_menu:
    time_delta = clock.tick(60) / 1000.0
    for event in pygame.event.get():  # this for-loop makes sure the game exits when clicking x
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            main_menu = False

        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            if event.user_type == pygame_gui.UI_BUTTON_PRESSED:
                if event.ui_element == start_button:
                    game = True
                    main_menu = False
                if event.ui_element == quit_button:
                    main_menu = False

        manager.process_events(event)

    manager.update(time_delta)
    redrawUI()


while game:

    for event in pygame.event.get():  # this for-loop makes sure the game exits when clicking x
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game = False

    # Life check
    for speedboat in speedboats:
        if speedboat.rect.y >= 734:
            speedboat.kill()
            lives -= 1

        if not speedboat.alive:
            speedboats.remove(speedboat)
    for pirate_boss in bosses:
        if pirate_boss.end_reached and not pirate_boss.killed:
            lives = 0

    if lives == 0:
        whale = Player(334, 650, 128, 128)  # Spawns the Player at the start of the game in the middle of the screen
        speedboat_locations = (125, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800)
        speedboats = pygame.sprite.Group()
        bosses = []
        beams = []
        cooldown = 0
        lives = 3
        score = 0
        speedboat_hits = 0
        multiplier = 1
        main_menu = True
        game = False


    # Basic cooldown for the projectiles of the player
    if cooldown > 0:
        cooldown += 1
    if cooldown > 50:
        cooldown = 0

    # Collision of attacks
    for beam in beams:
        if beam.checkCollision(speedboats):
            speedboat_hits += 1
            score += (25 * multiplier)
            beams.pop(beams.index(beam))
        for pirate_boss in bosses:
            if pirate_boss.alive and not pirate_boss.killed:
                if beam.y - beam.width < pirate_boss.hitbox[1] + pirate_boss.hitbox[3] and beam.y + beam.width > \
                        pirate_boss.hitbox[1]:
                    if beam.x + beam.height > pirate_boss.hitbox[0] and beam.x - beam.height < pirate_boss.hitbox[0] + \
                            pirate_boss.hitbox[2]:
                        pirate_boss.hitpoints -= beam.damage
                        beams.pop(beams.index(beam))
                        alive_check = pirate_boss.hit()
                        if alive_check:
                            multiplier += 1
                            bosses.remove(pirate_boss)

        if beam.y > 0:
            beam.y -= beam.speed  # This makes sure the bullet moves forward as long as it is not of the screen
            beam.rect.center = (beam.x, beam.y)
        else:
            beams.pop(beams.index(beam))  # If the bullet goes of the screen it gets removed from the list

    # --- PLAYER CONTROLS ---
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and whale.x > whale.mov_speed:
        # Makes sure the whale can move left
        # and prevents the whale from exiting the screen
        whale.x = whale.x - whale.mov_speed

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and whale.x < 800 - whale.mov_speed - whale.width:
        # Makes sure the whale can move right
        # and prevents the whale from exiting the screen
        whale.x = whale.x + whale.mov_speed

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and cooldown == 0:
        # This block of code takes care of the beam-projectile the player can shoot
        if len(beams) < 3:
            beams.append(
                Projectile(round(whale.x + (whale.width // 2) - (32 // 2)), round(whale.y - (32 // 2)), 32, 32, 2,
                           10, beam_sprite))
            # The beam gets spawned at the whale X/Y Coordinate. To make the beam appear in the middle and at the
            # nose we add half the sprites width - half the width of the projectile to the for the x coordinate
            # and we use the y coordinate - half the length of the projectile to make the attack spawn at the top
        cooldown = 1

    # --- ENEMY SPAWNING ---

    now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    spawn_time = 3000
    speedboat = Enemy(64, 64, 1)
    boss = Boss(1, 1, 256, 256, 1, 50)

    # Game loop to increase difficulty

    if score > 500:
        spawn_time = 2000

    if score > 1000:
        spawn_time = 1500

    if score > 5000:
        speedboat = Enemy(64, 64, 2)
        spawn_time = 2000

    if score > 10000:
        speedboat = Enemy(64, 64, 2)
        spawn_time = 1500

    if now - start > spawn_time:
        start = now
        speedboats.add(speedboat)

    if speedboat_hits >= 10:
        bosses.append(boss)
        speedboat_hits = 0

    redrawGameWindow()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Put it in a main function, catch the exception and display it. Also run in a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting game = False, but using that in the while loop.  As soon as game is set to False the while loop exits and the game ends.  If you want to do it this way, use another variable in the while loop:

```
running = True
while running:
  if game:
     game_loop()
  elif menu:
     menu_loop()
```

Then use game and menu as switches to decide which thing to show.